# php .tpl based content management system — pros and cons

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system

I work at a company which uses a legacy content management system based on php utilizing templates. I am fed up with it as it is vastly inferior to modern CMS' (i.e. Drupal), particularly due to poor AJAX implementation capability and general confusion of branched out template tree. It is within my power to switch to a newer CMS as long as I have solid arguments to back it up. I decided to turn to people on this site as I am not primarily a coder. What would be the main reason for letting go of the old system?

Best regards,

Mike

Comment: can you explain the current system in some more detail? what exactly do you mean with templates?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this legacy CMS is a bespoke development? You could argue that using an established open source CMS is a better option due to ongoing development and support - and, generally speaking, whenever some bolt-on functionality is required there is a good chance that a plugin or module has already been developed to offer that functionality.

So, my main argument would be support and development benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You could even argue that Yahoo! is using Drupal.